# Slot time consumed in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I ran a query which resulted in the below stats.

Elapsed time: 12.1 sec

Slot time consumed: 14 hr 12 min

total_slot_ms: 51147110 ( which is 14 hr 12 min)

We are on an on-demand pricing plan. So the max slots would be 2000. That being said, if I used 2000 slots for the whole 12.1 seconds span then I should end up with total_slot_ms as **24200000** ( which is **2000x12.1x1000**). However, the **total_slot_ms is 51147110**. Average number of slots used are **51147110/121000 = 4225** ( which is way above **2000**). Can some explain to me how I ended up using more than **2000 slots**?

Answer (score 3):

In a course of Google, there is an example where a query shows 13 "elapsed time" seconds and 50 minutes  of "slot time consumed". They says:

> Hey, across all of our workers, we did essentially 50 minutes of work massively in parallel, 50 minutes so that your query could be returned back in 13 seconds. Best of all for you, you don't need to worry about spinning up those workers, moving data in-between them, making sure they're sharing all their results between their aggregations. All you care about is writing the SQL, finding the insights, and then running that query in a very fast turnaround. But there is abstracted from you a lot of distributed parallel processing that's happening.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Increasing Bigquery slot capacity significantly improves overall query performance, despite the fact that slots amount is actually the subject for [Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs) restriction along Bigquery [on-demand](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand_pricing) pricing plan, exceeding slots limit does not charge you for additional costs:

> BigQuery slots are shared among all queries in a single project.
> BigQuery might burst beyond this limit to accelerate your queries.
>
> To check how many slots you're using, see [Monitoring BigQuery using
> Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring).

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery on-demand supports limited bursting.  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#December_10_2019

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check execution plan for the query and understand all different slot_time_ms for wait, read, write activities at each stage.  Since this is on-demand slots, you may see lots of wait time, that will add up into total time.
Besides bursting, each stage of explain pan will help you understand that total time is not necessarily actual slot consumption but equivalent slot consumption.